# AgGrid - Keep pinned column in excel export

Tags: excel, export, ag-grid

I want to know how can I keep pinned left columns in Excel export, like in the grid actually :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7eiT.png)

There is no option available for that ?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are trying to mean by keep pinned left columns in excel?

Comment: Something like that : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/freeze-panes-to-lock-rows-and-columns-dab2ffc9-020d-4026-8121-67dd25f2508f